# Facebook app like, not URL like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to set up a like button for my app. I have written this code:

```
<fb:like href="http://ilovecapitals.com" send="false" layout="standard" width="500" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

But it seems Facebook doesn't link the likes from here to the likes of the app. How do I add a like button on my page that actually 'likes' my app, not the URL itself?

Thank you!

P.S.: That URL is a Facebook application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "Like" a Facebook application then it's one of the two options:

1. The application profile page (for example the [FarmVile Page](http://www.facebook.com/FarmVille))
   should be something like:
   http://www.facebook.com/FarmVille (if you have enough fans) Or
   http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=APP_ID
2. Or the application Canvas Page (for example [FarmVile Game](http://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/))
   should be:
   http://apps.facebook.com/canvas_name/

Comment: If I make the like use the URL of the canvas page, users don't see posts from the generated community page... Any work around for that?